# How to position two divs on eachother?

Tags: jquery, css

So, I want to put three different divs on eachother. The top div would be a text (eg. white) which has a transparent background, the middle div would be an empty div with only a background color(eg. blue), different from the first div's text color, and the bottom div would be another empty div with a background color same as the top divs text color(so in this case white).

The reason I want to do this is to create a button, which is basically seems empty (the top and the bottom div color is the same), but when mouse is hovered  on, the middle div should be sliding up with that different color, so we could se the first div's text, and the middle div's background color.

And this whole thing would be in a Bootstrap container (you'll se in the example).

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-3">
  <div id="topdiv">Button</div>
  <div id="middlediv"></div>
  <div id="bottomdiv"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topdiv{
 background-color:transparent;
 color:white;
 z-index:100;
}

#middlediv{
 background-color:blue;
 z-index:99;
}

#bottomdiv{
 background-color:white;
 z-index:98;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#middlediv').hide();
$('#topdiv').mouseenter(function()
  $('#middlediv').slideDown();
)};
$('#topdiv').mouseleave(function()
  $('#middlediv').slideUp();
)};
});
```

I've tried it with absolute position, but the problem with that is that I can't align my text to where I want (in this case on the middle of the div). Text-align: center doesn't work.

The main problem is CSS so I mainly need your help with that. If jQuery is not working properly, I think I can handle that.

I hope you'll understand my idea and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need a background div.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.button div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.topdiv {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: transparent;
  z-index: 3;
}
.bottomdiv {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: top 1s;
}
.button:hover .bottomdiv {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <div class="topdiv">Button</div>
  <div class="bottomdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `position: absolute` for the three divs and `position: relative` for their container.

Comment: I've tried it, but the main problem is aligning the text at the center of the div.